# Why is only 2 of 10 selecting process notified when a socket become readable?

Tags: python, linux, sockets, select

There are 10 processes sharing a socket in my application.

They all wait for it to become readable using `select`.

But I notice in the application log that only **2** of these 10 processes any time the socket become readable.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Do the 2 processes also read from the socket?

Comment: @user2864740 All of them will call call `accept` on the readable socket.

Comment: @satoru Perhaps the traffic is not big enough, so 2 processes handle all of it?

Comment: @freakish In fact there's only one request in my experiment, I'm expecting all the processes to move on and try `accept`, and all but one of them should fail.

Comment: @freakish I don't quite understand the `race condition` part. Why does it happen? Doesn't `select` just notify all the waiting processes?

Comment: @satoru How did you test it? I mean what's the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *suspect* what's happening is that the first process is waking up, returning from select(), and calling accept() before the subsequent context switch to the other processes can occur.

I'm not sure what select() actually blocks on or how it wakes up. I suspect when it does wake up from it's waiting on, it re-checks the queue to see if data is still available. If not, it goes back to waiting.

I'll double-down on my hypothesis as well. The fact that 2 processes are waking up is indicative of the fact that you have a dual-core processor. If you had a quad-core, you might see up to 4 processes wake up simultaneously.

One simple way to prove this theory: Put a 2 second sleep() call just prior to calling accept(). I suspect you'll see all 10 processes waking up and logging an attempt to call accept.

If your goal is to have N processes (or threads) servicing incoming connections, your approach is probably still good.  You could probably switch from doing a select() call on a non-blocking socket, to just using a blocking socket that calls accept() directly.  When an incoming connection comes in, one of the processes will return from accept() with a valid client socket handle.  The others will still remain blocked.

Comment: I disagree with the theory. 1) I've done tests with `sleep` before `accept` - no difference. 2) In my case it is 3 processes out of 10 that wake up (4 cpu cores). However I've checked PIDs and they are random but always 3. I'm going to do more tests. Something seems to seriously broken with select (or at least Python's select).

Comment: @freakish - I appreciate the feedback. I was careful to call this a hypothesis/theory, since I haven't done any testing.  It would be great if there was code posted by the OP. I suspect there's more going on here. I may try my own repro tomorrow...

Comment: I've posted my own theory. :) I don't know what's going on under the hood but I've made some simple observations and posted some code.

Comment: @selbie You are on the right path. When I add a `sleep` before `accept`, more processes show up accepting.

Comment: +1: Yep, it seems that this actually is the correct theory. I've made some mistakes in tests.